# How to send Cookie from Server to the Users Browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, cookies

I am trying to understand cookies and their working
So I am trying to send the cookie from the server and set it to the user browser
But, in the inside `developer tools--> application-->cookie` I cant see my cookie present there and I cant understand why

This is a simple react app
This is my App.js

```js
function App() {

  async function Check() {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/check", {
      method: "GET",
    });
    const data = await response.text();
    console.log(data);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={Check}>CheckCookie</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my Server

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.send("Website Server");
})

app.get('/check', cors(), async (req, res) => {
  res.cookie('cookieName', 'SUCCESSFULL', {
      maxAge: 900000,
      httpOnly: false,
      secure: false,
      sameSite: 'Strict',
      domain: 'localhost'
   });
    res.send('Cookie set successfully');
});
  

app.listen(5000, () => console.log('Running on port 5000'));
```

Onclicking **"CheckCookie"** button "Cookie set successfully" is logged in the console but when I check `developer tools--> application-->cookie` I cant see my cookie there
[image]

[image]

Instead when I open networks tab there I can see the cookie sent in response
[image]

Why is this happening I can't understand, how doe's this work, please help.

Comment: You need to specify the `credentials` option in your fetch request, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change both sides (server.js and App.js)

##### Cookie handling

The [`react-cookie`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie) simplifies cookie handling for `max-age` handling.

There's no need to parse response headers from the server to extract the expiration time and full control over cookie management on the client-side, allowing you to easily adjust expiration times as needed without server-side dependencies.

##### Confirm expires in client UI.

When the "Set Cookie" button is clicked, we calculate the expiration time (expires) based on the current time (Date.now()) plus the desired duration (900 * 1000 milliseconds).

##### Server provides CORS

The `corsOptions` defines the CORS options to be used by the CORS middleware.
sets up the CORS middleware with the specified options.

The server will now allow requests from 'http://localhost:3000' (the origin of your React app) and will enable credentials (cookies) for these requests.

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000', // your React URL
  credentials: true // Enable credentials (cookies, HTTP authentication)
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

##### Express Server

As `server.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Allow requests only from your React app's origin
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true // Enable credentials (cookies, HTTP authentication)
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Website Server');
});

app.get('/check', async (req, res) => {
    res.cookie('cookieName', 'SUCCESSFULL', {
        maxAge: 900000,
        httpOnly: false,
        secure: false,
        sameSite: 'Strict',
        domain: 'localhost'
    });
    res.send('Cookie set successfully');
});

app.listen(5000, () => console.log('Running on port 5000'));
```

##### Client Side

`App.js`

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';

function App() {
  const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(['cookieName']);
  const [cookieStatus, setCookieStatus] = useState('');
  const [expiresAt, setExpiresAt] = useState('');

  const handleCheckCookie = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/check', {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include' // Include cookies in the request
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        const expiresInMs = response.headers.get('max-age') * 1000;
        const now = new Date();
        const expires = new Date(now.getTime() + expiresInMs);

        document.cookie = `cookieName=SUCCESSFULL;expires=${expires.toUTCString()};path=/;`;

        setCookieStatus('Cookie set successfully');
        setExpiresAt(expires.toLocaleString());
      } else {
        setCookieStatus('Failed to set cookie');
        setExpiresAt('');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error.message);
      setCookieStatus('Failed to set cookie');
      setExpiresAt('');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleCheckCookie}>Check Cookie</button>
      <p>{cookieStatus}</p>
      {expiresAt && <p>Cookie Expires At: {expiresAt}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

##### Result

[image]